# Unix join on multiple fields on two files

Tags: shell, unix, join, scripting, awk

I have a two files

cat test1.txt

```
1|2|3|4

2|3|4|4

3|4|5|5
```

cat test2.txt

```
1|2|4|5

2|3|5|6

3|5|7|7
```

My output should be

```
1|2|3|4|4|5

2|3|4|4|5|6
```

Its like joining two files on fields 1 and 2 and get the values of 1,2,3,4 from file 1 and 3,4, from file 2.

Please help me with this?

Comment: this would be pretty easy if you could use a database like sqlite - is that an option?

Answer (score 4):

```
awk -F\| 'NR == FNR {
  f2[$1, $2] = $3 OFS $4
  next
  }
($1, $2) in f2 {
  print $0, f2[$1, $2]
  }' OFS=\| test2.txt test1.txt
```

Comment: +1 for the best solution. I'd have used BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} rather than assigning them separately though.

Comment: Thanks Ed, thank you for all the useful posts on Usenet and here on stackoverflow!

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this in `perl`

```
paste -d '|' file1.txt file2.txt |
    perl -F'\|' -lane '
        print join "|", @F[0..3,6,7] if $F[0] eq $F[4] and $F[1] eq $F[5]
    '
```

And in `sh` :

```
#!/bin/sh

paste -d '|' test1.txt test2.txt | while IFS='|' read a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7 a8; do
    if [ $a1 -eq $a5 -a $a2 -eq $a6 ]; then
        echo "$a1|$a2|$a3|$a4|$a7|$a8"
    fi
done
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1|2|3|4|4|5
2|3|4|4|5|6
```

Comment: Your last line is wrong as there is not a match in both tables (supposed to match on the first 2 fields in each table)

Comment: @DaveRlz : OP is not clear for what he expect as last line

Comment: @sputnick The OP is pretty clear. They want a join on two first fields, that explains why there's two lines in the output.

Comment: @sputnick - he says ' like joining two files on fields 1 and 2'

Comment: @sputnick Nice - I've learned that I need to improve my shell programming.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, that works for your example:

```
 sed 's/|/+/' t1.txt>$$.tmp;sed 's/|/+/' t2.txt|join -t \| -j 1 $$.tmp -|sed 's/+/|/';rm $$.tmp
```

Comment: There's no need for a temporary file, you can use [process substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html): `sed ... | join -t \| -j 1 <(sed ...) - | ...`

Comment: Now I leant a new interesting and useful feature.

Answer (score 2):

This also seems to work:

```
$ sed 's/|/\t/2' 1.txt > 1_1.txt; sed 's/|/\t/2' 2.txt > 2_1.txt;
$ join -j1 1_1.txt 2_1.txt | tr ' ' '|'
$ rm 1_1.txt 2_1.txt
```

A one-liner without temporary file creation (thanks to @dbaupp):

```
$ join -j1 <(sed 's/|/\t/2' 1.txt) <(sed 's/|/\t/2' 2.txt) | tr ' ' '|'
```

Comment: There's no need for temporary files, you can use [process substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html): `join -j 1 <(sed ...) <(sed ...) | ...`

Comment: @dbaupp Ah! I was googling like crazy for that, but didn't know how it's called. Thanks!

Comment: Haha, I used to be in the same position! I knew what I wanted to do, but I didn't know the magic "process substitution" words to put into google!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
awk -F "|" '{getline a < "file1"}NR==1{print a, $3, $4 "\n"}NR==3{print a, $3, $4}' OFS="|" file2
```

Result:

```
$ awk -F "|" '{getline a < "file1"}NR==1{print a, $3, $4 "\n"}NR==3{print a, $3, $4}' OFS="|" file2
1|2|3|4|4|5

2|3|4|4|5|6
```