# Many to Many relationship in two files in unix

Tags: shell, unix, join, scripting, ksh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unix join on multiple fields on two files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13277350/unix-join-on-multiple-fields-on-two-files)

I need to get values from two files joining on fields 1 and 2 but the fields are not unique. I need to get all the values. For eg

$cat **test1.txt**

```
1|2|aaa|bb
1|2|bbb|cc
1|3|ccc|dd
1|3|ddd|ee
```

$cat **test2.txt**

```
1|2|ccc|dd
1|2|eee|ff
1|2|fff|dd
1|3|ggg|hh
```

**Desired Output:**

```
1|2|aaa|bb|ccc|dd
1|2|aaa|bb|eee|ff
1|2|aaa|bb|fff|dd
1|2|bbb|cc|ccc|dd
1|2|bbb|cc|eee|ff
1|2|bbb|cc|fff|dd
1|3|ccc|dd|ggg|hh
1|3|ddd|ee|ggg|hh
```

Normal `join` is not working. How can I get this to work?

Comment: When you say '`join` is not working', can you show your `join` command that doesn't work, what it produces, and why it's wrong?

Comment: [My answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13277654/1258041) from your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13277350/1258041) produces the desired output just fine. Others probably do, too. Why are you asking another question?

Comment: @Lev - my previous question is different from this one. Here I have mentioned many to many.

Comment: But my answer still works, and you've already got [one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13335301/1258041) equivalent to it here. Maybe I'm missing something, though...

Answer (score 0):

an awk one-liner works for your example:

```
 awk -F'|' 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=FS$3FS$4;next;}{for(x in a)if(x~"^"$1"\\|"$2)print $0a[x]}' test2.txt test1.txt
```

test:

```
kent$  head test*.txt
==> test1.txt <==
1|2|aaa|bb
1|2|bbb|cc
1|3|ccc|dd
1|3|ddd|ee

==> test2.txt <==
1|2|ccc|dd
1|2|eee|ff
1|2|fff|dd
1|3|ggg|hh

kent$  awk -F'|' 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=FS$3FS$4;next;}{for(x in a){ if(x~"^"$1"\\|"$2) print $0a[x]} }' test2.txt test1.txt 
1|2|aaa|bb|eee|ff
1|2|aaa|bb|fff|dd
1|2|aaa|bb|ccc|dd
1|2|bbb|cc|eee|ff
1|2|bbb|cc|fff|dd
1|2|bbb|cc|ccc|dd
1|3|ccc|dd|ggg|hh
1|3|ddd|ee|ggg|hh
```

Answer (score 0):

The `join` command only joins on a single field, so you need to munge the data so that you have a single field to join on.

```
sed 's/|/=/' test1.txt > test3.txt
sed 's/|/=/' test2.txt > test4.txt
join -t'|' test3.txt test4.txt | sed 's/=/|/'
```